# Java Nullpointer Exception in ArrayList (Lib GDX)

Tags: java, android, class, libgdx

I have a problem with a "Nullpointer Exception" in LIb GDX.
When calling the method " public static ArrayList getList(Stage stage, String className)"
I get the Nullpointer Exception.

Would be very grateful for help...

[image]

Here the function:

```
 public  static ArrayList<BaseActor> getList(Stage stage, String className)
{
    ArrayList<BaseActor> list = new ArrayList<BaseActor>();

    Class theClass;
    theClass=null;

    try
    {
        theClass = Class.forName(className);  }
    catch (Exception error)
    {  error.printStackTrace();  }

    for (Actor a : stage.getActors())
    {
        if ( theClass.isInstance( a ) )
            list.add( (BaseActor)a );
    }

    return list;
}
```

Here is the call to the function:

```
 public void update(float dt)
{

    try{
        for (BaseActor rockActor : BaseActor.getList(mainStage, "Rock"))
            turtle.preventOverlap(rockActor);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {  error.printStackTrace();  } ......
```

...

Comment: If `theClass = Class.forName(className);` fails, variable `theClass` the class remains `null`. In this scenario you need better error handling than simply printing stacktrace.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: One way is to throw unchecked exception and handle it properly somewhere else (if the error is not recoverable, this one is not, most of the time). Or you can return an empty list. Depends on what you need to happen if exception occurs when instantiating `theClass`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the result of the `try`/`catch` could result in `theClass` still being null.  One way to handle this would be to include your list logic *inside* of the `try`, like this:

```
try
{
    theClass = Class.forName(className);

    for (Actor a : stage.getActors())
    {
        if ( theClass.isInstance( a ) )
            list.add( (BaseActor)a );
    }
}
catch (Exception error)
{  error.printStackTrace();  }

return list;
```

And Chaosfire is right; you may need to do more than just print the stack trace.

Comment: okay, but what can i do?

Comment: @HermannGo it depends on what you're trying to do overall.  But for starters, perhaps also catching for a `NullPointerException` and/or `ClassNotFoundException`with a custom error message would do it.  Something like: `"Class.forName for " + className + " has failed.  Please check the validity of className"`